# Find numbers to satisfy the condition

Tags: c#, algorithm

Suppose you have one million consecutive integer numbers.
           Return all possible values of a,b and c such that

```
      a+b+c<=d.
      d will be provided to you.
      ex: if the numbers are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
      and d=7
       [1,2,3]
       [1,2,4]
       [1,2,3] will be same as [1,3,2] and [3,2,1]...
```

Because one million is too big, in the example I adopted 1000 as an example. Also for the convenience, I used 1 to 1000 as the data set. 
Suppose

```
      `a<b<c`
```

Thus `3*a<1000`==> a<333.33, so I extract `a` from 1 to 333.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int d = 519;
        var setA = Enumerable.Range(1, 333);
        IEnumerable<int> value = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);
        var result =     (from a in setA
                          from b in value
                          from c in value
                          where a!=b && a!=c && b!=c && a + b + c <= d
                          select new {a,b,c}).ToList().Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

It is slow and throw an `System.OutOfMemoryException` exception.....

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are the numbers all positive?  If so then you can first filter to just where `i<d`, then to where `a < d/3`

Comment: Yes, we can assume all positive numbers in the set.

Comment: @DStanley more like a > 2 and a < d - 3

Comment: @Serpiton not if `a < b < c` (since `1,2,3` and `3,2,1` are equivalent sets).

Comment: @DStanley you are right it'll be `c > 2` and `c < d - 3` since is c the max value

Comment: Why downvote, it throw an exception. It is the right forum, not code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with the `index` and your selection for each of the `for` loops, assuming the input is sorted. The first one should be one third of the main array, second loop should be not more than half but starting from the index of the first loop. something like this:

```
    const int totalElements = 1000;
        const int target = 1000;
        var value = Enumerable.Range(1, totalElements).OrderBy(dd => dd).ToList();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        var result = new List<int[]>();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count / 3; i++)
        {
            var a = value[i];

            for (int j = i + 1; j < value.Count / 2; j++)
            {
                var b = value[j];

                for (int k = j + 1; k < value.Count; k++)
                {
                    var c = value[k];

                    if (a + b + c <= target)
                    {
                        var newR = new[] { a, b, c };
                        result.Add(newR);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Total result count: " + result2.Count);
```

For 1000 it's taking 4.9 seconds on my lousy machine, where as the LINQ is throwing `outofmemory exception`. On top of that you have to add some sort of equality comparison in the LINQ otherwise you'll get results like 1+2+3 and 3+2+1, and using the index only you get rid of that.

You can also adjust the range by doing something like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count / 3; i++)
        {
            var a = value[i];

            var index = value.IndexOf(target - a) + 1;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < index; j++)
            {
                var b = value[j];

                var remainingIndex = value.IndexOf(target - (a + b)) + 1;

                for (int k = j + 1; k < remainingIndex; k++)
                {
                    var c = value[k];

                    if (a + b + c <= target)
                    {
                        var newR = new[] { a, b, c };
                        result.Add(newR);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It might be better if the values are sequential like this example and you can find the index easily. If that's not the case you have to find the index by `Binary Search` but it'll probably be similar performance anyway.

Comment: "The first one should be one third of the main array". Why?

Comment: @Tarik As explained in the question

Comment: Shall we assume the numbers are consecutive?

Comment: Yes, that assumption was made in some cases as mentioned above

Comment: The fact that you need to check each result shows that numbers are taken into account that are no candidates - this can be further optimized :-)

Comment: I think you can improve the range for `j` because `value.IndexOf(target - a) + 1` is too high. It should have been `value.IndexOf(target - a)/2 + 1`, because `(b+c<d-a)` and `b<(d-a)/2`

Answer (score 1):

Narrowing down `a` to `1...333` is a good idea. You can further improve your code though by using the fact that `a < b < c`, so `b,c in Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)` is suboptimal.

You can define lower bounds and upper bounds for `b` and `c` depending on the given numbers `a` and `b` respectively:

```
a < b => b >= a + 1, b in Enumerable.Range(a + 1, ...)
b < c => c must be in Enumerable.Range(b + 1, ...)
```

Furthermore you can define bounds for `a` and `b` like that:

- Since `b >= a + 1` and `a + b + c <= total`, `a + (a + 1) + ((a + 1) + 1) <= total` must hold true also. That is, `a < total / 3` is not sufficient. It is `a <= (total - 3) / 3`
- Similarly `a + b + (b + 1) <= total`, that is, `b <= (total - a - 1) / 2`
- And of course, `a + b + c <= total` translates to `c <= total - a - b`

You can make use of that by nesting the iterations and using `SelectMany` to flatten the result list:

```
        var result = Enumerable.Range(1, (total - dba - dca) / 3)
            .SelectMany(
                a => Enumerable.Range(a + 1, (total - a - dcb) / 2 - a)
                    .SelectMany(
                        b => Enumerable.Range(b + 1, (total - a - b) - b)
                            .Select(c => new { a, b, c })));
```

As for your performance and out-of-memory issue:

Remove the `ToList()` from your LINQ query. It causes all results to be loaded into memory before you start processing them. Since you only want to print out the tuples, you don't need to load all of them into memory. This is the big strengh of LINQ - it just returns an enumerator without actually calculating the result. If you remove the `ToList()` from the LINQ query, the for-each loop will calculate one result per iteration, print it out, and forget it again.

---

As an explanatory answer to your comments:

The implementation of `Enumerable.Range` looks like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        yield return start + i;
}
```

Implementation of `SelectMany`:

```
private static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectManyIterator<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)
{
  foreach (TSource source1 in source)
  {
    foreach (TResult result in selector(source1))
      yield return result;
  }
}
```

So for example,

```
foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 10).SelectMany(n => Enumerable.Range(1, n)))
{ /* do something */ }
```

conceptually translates to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var n = 1 + i;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        var result = 1 + j;

        /* do something */  // <- processes the current result and forgets it again
    }
}
```

However, when you add `ToList`:

```
foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 10).SelectMany(n => Enumerable.Range(1, n)).ToList())
{ /* do something */ }
```

this translates to:

```
var list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var n = 1 + i;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        var item = 1 + j;
        list.Add(item); // <- puts the current result in a list
    }
}

// list content: 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...

foreach (var item in list)
{ /* do something */ }
```

Comment: -@chiccodoro, it is a good idea. And do you think that LINQ is slow? I am not sure if we could use `for` loop to handle it.

Comment: -@chiccodoro, your code is not working. An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. I guess because of SelectMany. Please test it in your box.

Comment: @Love, honestly, no, I tested it with a number of 10 only to make sure it works. I just wanted to point you to a handful of improvements. "slow" and out-of-memory-exception are slightly vage. To define "slow" you need a time limit, and for an out-of-memory-exception you need a memory limit. You did not provide either, but I am pretty confident that my answer takes less memory and less time than your orginal code.

Comment: -@chiccodoro, it works out after I removed `ToList()`. Just wonder how an enumerator holds the per result? The `foreach` code loop is under the result. I assume that it calculated it.

Comment: @Love: I am glad to hear that! Next I am wondering how much this differs from the performance of AD.Net's answer. I expect the difference to be rather small.

Comment: @Love: As for the explanation: Your LINQ statement builds a tree of enumerators. An enumerator is an object that allows to iterate over a collection. The enumerator itself does not hold the collectoin. It only keeps track of "where" it currently is. `for each` retrieves the next element in each iteration. Only then it is actually calculated. Before your for loop starts, nothing is done. `ToList` however is an instruction to iterate through all results and put them into a list object.

Comment: -@chiccodoro, thanks for nice explaination. But if without ToList(), you still have `new [] { n }` in your code, in which hold a big memory same as list. I think that if using list, it just move the dat a of `new [] { n }` to the list. Perhaps I doubled the memory. Am I right?

Comment: @Love, `new [] { n }` was a bad, confusing example. I replaced it with something else. I just try to make the point that `Enumerable.Range`, `SelectMany`, and `Select` all return enumerators and each iteration in for-each only pulls one item from the enumerator at a time, whereas `ToList` puts all items in a list.

Comment: But for my particular case, you still need to hold `c => new { a, b, c }` in the memory then we can know how many of the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to store the numbers in a SortedSet Class. You can the do the following (pseudocode):

```
For each n in GetViewBetween (1, d)
    For each m in GetViewBetween (n+1, d-n)
        For each k in GetViewBetween (m+1, d-n-m)
            Store or print or callback or return with continuation the Tuple object with n, m, k
        Loop
    Loop
Loop
```

Comment: To downvoters, leave a message so as to give a chance to fix the answer.

Comment: (I am not the downvoter). Your answer does basically the same as mine, just in different notation: GetViewBetween (1, d) == Enumerable.Range(1, d), and the nested for-each is equivalent to the nested SelectMany. So I think your answer is good. It is not very clear what value it adds to the already existing answers though, you might want to make that point clearer.

Comment: @chiccodoro except that I did not assume that the numbers were consecutive. Moreover using a sorted set allows to access a range of numbers in linear time. Now, assuming consecutive integers, three nested do loops does the job without the overhead of LINQ or Enumerators.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you a geometry representation: Imagine, that your 'd' is sum of triangle borders. Thuse, you need to find all triangles that fit. In your code you double variants: (a+b+c) = (b+c+a), for example. But if you make 3 loops for each triangle side, then it would be faster.

Comment: And you cannot enumerate all possible variants faster, then O(d), where d = is maximum length of triangle borders.